# Excel Sumifs with Vertical and horizontal over many columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table and would like to return the sum based on criteria in column A, column B and row 1.  In the below example I am returning the sum of "Gross (£)", for "UPC 3" for the dates between "4th and 6th and February" inclusive.  I have highlighted the cells yellow I require to add up which gives the answer of £16.10.

Any help in creating a formula which can calculate the £16.10 answer would be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance, Alan.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:G9*(B2:B9=B14)*(A2:A9=B13)*(C1:G1>=B15)*(C1:G1<=B16))
```

or if you want to use `SUMIFS()`:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(C2:G9,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A9=B13)*(B2:B9=B14),),0),0),C1:G1,">="&B15,C1:G1,"<="&B16)
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you.  Is it easy to adapt so it returns the average?

Comment: Your edit using the sumif has allowed me to tweak it to averageifs.  Many thanks.

Comment: Apologies, would it be easy to amend the formula so if the UPC appeared more than once it would still sum up the additional rows.?

Comment: @AlanTingey, it does so with the `SUMPRODUCT()` variant yes

Comment: but I am unable to convert the sumproductI() to give me an average... or is there an easy solution to that?

Comment: The solution could be to use one `SUMPRODUCT()` to get the total sum, and another `SUMPRODUCT()` to count. Devide the two. Basically you only need to leave out the `C2:G9*` in the 2nd one to get the count.

Comment: Happy to add a new question if we have veered away too much from the original question.

Comment: oh i see, perfect.  That makes sense now.  Many thanks.